# Usage of "How I wish I could..."

Tags: phrases

How and when is the phrase "How I wish I could..." used?

I came across this phrase at at least two instances:

1. How I wish he could question the Indian powers!
2. How I wish I could. But I have a real job. I think you should go, the cool, fresh air of Kashmir will do you a world of good.

Comment: You could replace the word "How" with the exclamation "Oh!" and the meaning would stay about the same: _Oh! I wish he could question the Indian powers!_

Comment: Best usage:  How I wish I could recollect pi. // "Eureka," cried the great inventor. // Christmas Pudding; Christmas Pie // Is the problem's very center.

Comment: Both the instances are fine.

Answer (score 1):

How I wish...

is an exclamation expressing that your wish is an *ardent* one.

You can have wishes you don't really care too much about:

> I wish they had put a little more mustard on this burger.

And you can have wishes that  are really important to you:

> How I wish  I'd been able to see him off!  He'll be overseas for two years.